# How to convert "2017-04-03T00:00:00" date format to "2017-04-02 03:30:00+05:30" in java?

Tags: java, date, grails

My application generates the date as  *"2017-04-03T00:00:00"* format, and I am trying to save it in Postgres DB with

> *"2017-04-03 00:00:00+05:30"*

. With sql query, the date gets saved in the DB properly. But when I am trying to save it with GROM `save()` method, it is showing

> *"on field 'startdate': rejected value [2017-04-03T00:00:00]"*

I am using `org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormInstanceApi.save()` API. Here is my code snippet:

```
def update(name, startdate, enddate) {
    TestExt mydomain = new TestExt (name: name, startdate:startdate, enddate:enddate)
    if(mydomain.hasErrors() || !mydomain.save(flush:true)){
        println mydomain.errors
    }
    // TestExt.executeUpdate("update TestExt set name='"+name +"', start_date='"+startdate +"', end_date='"+enddate +"' where id=1")
}
```

Can anyone help me with that?
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: What is `GROM save()`?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: The only answer we can give you when you do **not** post your code here: learn to use a debugger. We can only help with code that we see.

Comment: I am using org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormInstanceApi.save() API.

Comment: def update(name, startdate, enddate) {
  
   TestExt mydomain = new TestExt (name: name, startdate:startdate, enddate:enddate)
   if(mydomain.hasErrors() || !mydomain.save(flush:true)){
    println mydomain.errors
   }
   
  
  
 // TestExt.executeUpdate("update TestExt set name='"+name  +"', start_date='"+startdate  +"', end_date='"+enddate  +"' where id=1")
   
 }

Comment: here is my code snippet. Please take a look

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet. It is quite unreadable in the comment. Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43653572/edit), add the snippet and format it nicely.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the field you're trying to insert this value is a TIMESTAMP. Have you tried to cast it?

```
SELECT CAST('2017-04-03T00:05:00' AS TIMESTAMP);
```

Comment: The problem here is actually the user has defined `def update(name, startdate, enddate) ` there is no definition of what start or end date can be therefore it will accept string or date. The actual issue is the params of date passed in is in String format and needs to be in date format. The solution is to set your default date format try googling that term and the answer to this entire question lies there. Sorry not @ jim but @mam